# Filter by day and reducing region by polygon using image collection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, tile-reduce

My overall program is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/88d2664f2057ecf9274469be4c119f27). I have an aerosol index that I already reduced for daily means:

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var Iraq = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Iraq'));

var airq_19 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_AER_AI')
  .select('absorbing_aerosol_index').
  map(function(image){return image.clip(Iraq)}) 
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31');


var daysOfMonth = ee.List.sequence(1, 31); //Restricted to first 31 for trial run

var composites = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(daysOfMonth.map(function(d) {
  var filtered = airq_19.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange({
    start: d,
    field: 'day_of_year'
  }));
  return filtered.mean().set('day', d);
}));

print("Composite aerosol", composites);
```

I also have a grid over Iraq:

```
//Bounding box 
var lat_start = 29.0990251735;
var lat_end = 37.3852635768;
var lon_start = 38.7923405291; 
var lon_end = 48.5679712258;

//Set number of grid cells
var num_cells = 10;
var lon_edge = (lon_end-lon_start)/Math.sqrt(num_cells);
var lat_edge = (lat_end-lat_start)/Math.sqrt(num_cells);
// 3) Create the grid
var polys = [];
var polys_line = [];
var cell_id = 0;
for (var lon = lon_start; lon < lon_end; lon += lon_edge) {
  var x1 = lon;
  var x2 = lon + lon_edge;
  for (var lat = lat_start; lat < lat_end; lat += lat_edge) {
    cell_id = cell_id + 1;
    var y1 = lat;
    var y2 = lat + lat_edge;

    polys.push(ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2), {label: cell_id}));
  }
}

//Final grid
var grid = ee.FeatureCollection(polys).filterBounds(Iraq);
print('Final grid', grid);
Map.addLayer(grid);
```

I am trying to build a function that identifies mean aerosol by day within each grid. I have developed a function that is currently not running. It looks like this:

```
var daysOfYear = ee.List.sequence(1, 365); 
var counts = grid.map(function(feature) {  
  var counts = daysOfYear.map(function(day) {
    var dayEvents = composites 
      .filter(ee.Filter.eq("day", day))
      .filterBounds(feature.geometry())
      .reduceRegions ({
    collection: grid,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 100
      });
    var key = ee.String('day').cat(ee.String(ee.Number(day).int()))
    return ee.List([key, dayEvents.size()]);  
  }).flatten()
  return feature.set(ee.Dictionary(counts))
});

print("aerosol by grid and day", counts.limit(10));
```

The function above results in the error:

```
composites.filter(...).filterBounds(...).reduceRegions is not a function
```

Is the issue that the aerosol composites are stored as an image collection? If no, then how can I modify the function above such that the function will produce the intended feature collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is indeed what is happening. You defined your filters correctly to just return one image, but `filter` return an imageCollection, even if it just consist of one image. Therefore, apply `first()` on that imagecollection to get only the image you want and your defined function should work correctly.

```
// check what filtering of the image collection 'composites' does
print('check filter', composites .filter(ee.Filter.eq("day", 1)).filterBounds(grid.first().geometry()))
// return always (the way you defined this, one image, but in a collectin)
print('get the image of the collection', composites .filter(ee.Filter.eq("day", 1)).filterBounds(grid.first().geometry()).first())
```

Moreover, you are mapping over each feature of the grid, but then later using the complete grid as input for the `reduceRegions` function. That is not necasarry. I am going to give you a solution you probably are aiming to.

However, not all image collection contain an image (as some dates not exist), therefore use the following to filter out image without a band:

```
// filter out image without bands
composites = composites.filter(ee.Filter.listContains("system:band_names", "absorbing_aerosol_index"));
print(composites)
```

Therefore, we'd better map over the image collection and use `reduceRegions` in one go:

```
// map over the image collection
var counts = ee.FeatureCollection(composites.map(function(image) {

    // apply the mean reducer 
    var dayEvents = image.reduceRegions({
      collection: grid,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: 100
    });
  var key = ee.String('day').cat(ee.String(ee.Number(image.get('day')).int()));

  return dayEvents;  
})).flatten();
```

Then see in the [link to the code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/91a9fbf4f63af80d0cb9c3e1168ad0ae) how to implement this in your function. Let me know if this is what you needed.